# List argument for NonlinearModelFit

Tags: fitting

If I have a function of list argument (presumably with large number of entries), how can I pass it to `NonlinearModelFit`? I don't want to pass it by pattern checking (`f[x_?(VectorQ[#, Numeric!]&)]`) because apparently it turns off some intermediate operations and heavily slows down the fitting.

Example:

```
f[x_, a_] := Exp[-Sin[{x, x}.a]];

NonlinearModelFit[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 3}], f[x, a], {{a, {1, 2}}},
  x]
```

Comment: What are your fit parameters?

Comment: @BlacKow I corrected, does my question make sense?

Comment: What are dimensions of `x` and `a`?

Comment: Oh... I think I understand now, you want to find a matrix that fits your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always done it like this, and I've done fits with a few hundred parameters so it isn't **that** much of a pain.

The point is that you define the function `f` to take a vector input for `x` and `a`. Then you define a vector of variables, {x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfSka.png), x[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u6jT.png),....} and that is the fourth argument to [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html). The second argument to `NonlinearModelFit` needs to be a scalar function, where all the matrix expansions have happened already. In the case here, `f[variables, parameters]` evaluates the matrix product before it does any fitting.

```
parameters = Array[a, {7}]
variables = Array[x, {7}]
guess = Range[7]
f[x_, a_] := Exp[-Sin[x.a]];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {40, 8}], 
  f[variables, parameters], Transpose[{parameters, guess}], 
  Evaluate@variables]
nlm["BestFitParameters"]


(* {a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7]} *)

(* {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7]} *)

(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} *)
```

[image]

```
(* {a[1] -> 3.47592, a[2] -> 0.155765, a[3] -> 4.18935, a[4] -> 1.59981, 
 a[5] -> 7.34998, a[6] -> 1.60615, a[7] -> 10.3245} *)
```

Comment: But your `x` is a scalar and `a` is a vector. I think he wants `x` as vector and `a` as a matrix.

Comment: That isn't how I read his code, he gives an initial guess for `a` that is a vector.  Likewise he takes the `Sin` of `{x, x}.a` which to me implies `{x, x}.a` is a scalar.  Sure, he could be taking advantage of the listability of `Sin` and `Exp`, but the way it is written `x` should be a scalar.

Comment: Well if you look at it your way, there is no need to have several `a`s, because you could just replace it with `Exp[-Sin[ax]]`. Look at the edit history of his question, his last edit confused it a bit.

Comment: Right, but I'm sure this is just a minimal simple working example.  I'm gonna go on the assumption that the argument of `Sin` and `Exp` should be a scalar, but this can be easily extended to account for a vector x as well.  Whether it's `x.a.x` or `x.a`, it's easily extended.  I think the main point is that you want to do the matrix alagebra on your function rather than asking `FindFit` to do it.

Comment: How do you make `x` a vector? That's the thing I can't figure out

Comment: You don't, you define the function `f` to take a vector input for x and a.  Then you define a vector of variables, `{x[1], x[2],....}` and **that** is the fourth argument to `NonlinearModelFit`.  The second argument to `NonlinearModelFit` needs to be a scalar function, where all the matrix expansions have happened already.  In the case above, `f[variables, parameters]` evaluates the matrix product before it does any fitting.

Comment: @BlacKow - it's possible I'm missing the point  :-)

Comment: Actually I totally see the point now, thank you! I was struggling with `a` being a matrix and how to make it work, I think it figured it out now.

Comment: @JasonB Why do you need `Evaluate@variables` ?

Comment: @BlacKow I might not need it lol, when I get errors I'll try throwing in an `Evaluate ` or two, then I don't delete them before posting.  I'm home so I can't check if it's needed at all here. Will delete if not

Comment: @JasonB This approach of throwing `Evaluate`s here and there isn't unfamiliar :) It seems to work without it though.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a real answer, but applying @JasonB's approach to 2D case. So `x` is a vector and `a` is a matrix.
I simplified the function to see how good is the fit in simple case.

We have noisy `data` and we want to try to find fit and compare it with `test`

```
f[x_, a_] := Exp[-x.a.x];
test = {{0.75, 0.}, {0, 0.25}};
data = Flatten[{#, f[#, test] + RandomReal[{-0.05, 0.05}]}] & /@ 
   Tuples[Range[-4, 4, 0.1], 2];

parameters = Array[a, {2, 2}];
z = Array[x, {2}];
paramFull = Flatten[#, 1] &@Map[{#, 0} &, parameters, {2}]; (* sets initial guess to zero for all parameters *)

fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, f[z, parameters], paramFull, z];
parameters /.fit["BestFitParameters"]

(*{{0.748501, 96.3969}, {-96.3989, 0.248822}}*)
```

So the fit is pretty good (although the non diagonal elements are way off it doesn't matter, because antisymmetric matrix gives zero in $x^TAx$).

```
Show[ListPointPlot3D[data, PlotRange -> Full], 
 Plot3D[fit[x, y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> Full, 
  Mesh -> None]]
```

[image]