# Solve for an element of a vector

Tags: equation-solving, summation, vector

I would like to solve for an element of a vector. Suppose $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and I want to find a solution to the following

$\sum_{i=1}^n w_i = c$

where $c$ is some constant and only one $w_k$ is unknown (for some $k \in [1,n]$). (i.e. $w_k = c - \sum_{i\neq k} w_i$).

I'm not sure how to work with vectors in Mathematica. What I have tried so far is:

```
Solve[Sum[w[i], {i, 1, n}] == c, w[k]]
```

The output is:

```
{}
```

I know I'm not handling the vector `w` properly. I've looked around and I can't seem to find a proper way to define `w` as a vector. Do I need to define `k` and `n` to have a value, or can they be constants? I've tried using `Array[w,n]` but `n` needs to have a value for this to work.

Comment: your result can be expressed as : `c - Sum[ Boole[i != k] w[i] , {i, n}]` . There isnt a built in way to directly get there though AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is exactly what you expect but try

```
 Table[Subscript[w, i], {i, 1, 10}]
 Solve[Total[Table[Subscript[w, i], {i, 1, 10}]] == c, Subscript[w, 4]]
```

In what you normaly write you implicitely postulate that $k \in \{1, 10\}$. I think such a theoretical formula is beyond the capacity of any computer algebra system.

Comment: That is quite close, you have `n=10` and `k=4`. I would like to not specify what `n` and `k` are. (which would require the closed form of the sum, i think).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, but following [112606](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112545/list-argument-for-nonlinearmodelfit/112606#112606), you can do something like this

```
k = 5;
n = 10;
Solve[Total[Array[w, n]] == c, w[k]]

(* {{w[5] -> c - w[1] - w[2] - w[3] - w[4] - w[6] - w[7] - w[8] - w[9] - w[10]}} *)
```